# SQL Select Query - Two Tables

Tags: sql

I'd like to perform a SQL SELECT query which will go across two tables. I understand I'll need to use a join, but I'm not entirely sure how this would work (apologies - quite new to SQL).

```
SELECT COUNT(RSO_ParentID) AS 'Calls in Queue'
FROM Task, Incident
WHERE Task.OwnerTeam = '2nd Line Support'
    AND (Task.Status='Accepted' OR Task.Status='Waiting')
    AND (Incident.Status='Waiting');
```

But this returns 6,749,340 results when there should only be about 150, so I've clearly gone wrong somewhere - but can't figure out where.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. If there's any additional information that would be useful, let me know and I'll gladly provide you with further details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the relationship between tables task and Incident??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many different ways to solve a problem with SQL and a number of ways to filter out and reduce your dataset to what you want to see. Lets look at your original SQL Statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(RSO_ParentID) AS 'Calls in Queue'
FROM Task, Incident
WHERE Task.OwnerTeam = '2nd Line Support'
    AND (Task.Status='Accepted' OR Task.Status='Waiting')
    AND (Incident.Status='Waiting');
```

Selecting from 2 tables is not recommended. Remember `SQL` is a `Relational Database Management System`.  What you need to know is, is there a relationship between `Tasks` and `Incidents`.

If you want the subset of two tables combined you have to know their relationhip. Since I dont know your full schema here is a illustrative example. You will have to apply your exact scenario.

For example say there a TaskID in the Incident table so you know that this task was an incident, you would do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(RSO_ParentID) AS 'Calls in Queue'
FROM Task t 
JOIN Incident i
ON t.TaskID = i.TaskID
WHERE Task.OwnerTeam = '2nd Line Support'
    AND (Task.Status='Accepted' OR Task.Status='Waiting')
    AND (Incident.Status='Waiting');
```

That will give you only tasks that were incidents. Probably the 150 you were looking for.

**EDIT:**
Another note one JOINS. There are different types of `JOIN`. `RIGHT`, `LEFT`, `INNER`, `OUTER`. The most common is an `INNER JOIN` which can also be done by simply a `JOIN`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I would venture to guess since I took the time to explain joins and how it works, and how he should apply it to his problem is probably why.  Matt, I am glad that this answer helped you. I had difficulty with JOINS because nobody ever explained it. I hope that this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT COUNT(RSO_ParentID) AS 'Calls in Queue' 
FROM Task JOIN Incident 
ON --task.somecolumn = incident.somecolumn
WHERE Task.OwnerTeam='2nd Line Support'
AND (Task.Status='Accepted' OR Task.Status='Waiting')
AND Incident.Status='Waiting'
```

You don't have a `join` condition in your query, which means it would give a `catersian product` (product of rows in both tables) as the result. Include the `join` condition to make it work.

Comment: Thanks - the following has worked a treat:

`SELECT COUNT(A.RSO_ParentID) AS 'Calls in Waiting State' 
FROM Task A
INNER JOIN Incident B
ON A.RSO_ParentID = B.IncidentNumber
WHERE A.OwnerTeam='2nd Line Support' AND (A.Status='Accepted' OR A.Status='Waiting') AND (B.Status='Waiting');`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `JOIN` condition between the two tables.  Simple rule:  *Never* use a comma in the `FROM` clause.  Here is a guess:

```
SELECT COUNT(RSO_ParentID) AS CallsinQueue
FROM Task t JOIN
     Incident i
     ON t.TaskId = i.TaskId
WHERE t.OwnerTeam = '2nd Line Support' AND
      t.Status IN ('Accepted', 'Waiting') AND 
      i.Status = 'Waiting';
```

Other suggestions:

- Use table aliases.  They make the table easier to write and to read.
- Use `IN`, instead of a bunch of equality conditions.
- Don't put column aliases in single quotes.  Although this is allowed, it often leads to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(RSO_ParentID) AS 'Calls in Queue' 
FROM Task INNER JOIN Incident ON Task.ID = Incident.ID
WHERE Task.OwnerTeam='2nd Line Support' 
AND (Task.Status='Accepted' OR Task.Status='Waiting') 
AND (Incident.Status='Waiting');
```

Assuming that the two tables are linked using the ID column.(*You can change it to the correct column name*). Presently your query is doing the cartesian product of the two tables since the two tables are not linked to each other.